# NinjaKiwi- Account Inactive, or unaccessable

Tags: account-recovery

Oh no, my account can't be accessed on NinjaKiwi. First off, what does that mean? Or is it that I'm inactive? Being inactive should have nothing to do with unable to login. I've heard that you could be banned. Now is this even true though? I guess that I have been inactive to NinjaKiwi, but after many attempts after being inactive, I still can't login. What is the problem?
[image: I can't seem to login!]

I am using Chrome.

**Edit**: It did redirect me to the register page, but for the ones who think it is a database space issue, it's not. When I tried re-registering, it said someone has used that Username and Email already.

Comment: This really is rather a support issue. You should contact the help desk for that site.

Answer (score 0):

1. Try clearing your cache and cookies. [This link](http://www.wikihow.com/Clear-Your-Browser's-Cache) will explain how for most browsers.
2. Or you could try using an entirely different browser like Firefox or Internet Explorer
3. If that doesn't work, you could try using a proxy browser. A proxy browser is a website that allows you to browse the internet anonymously and clears all previous browser history and cache/cookies. It can enable someone to access blocked websites or accounts at a workplace, school or even sites or accounts blocked by the service providers by hiding your IP for you automatically. If you use one of these proxy browsers you might be able to access your account anonymously with out any problem. And worry not, it is completely legal and free of charge. (e.g.: http://hidemyass.com/)

If none of these methods work for you, you can always try (if you haven't already) to contact the administrators of Ninja Kiwi through email. I know it seems I am stating the obvious but most website administrators can be helpful, and hopefully able to restore your account automatically if you struggle with restoring it manually.